# Hibernate hangs during SELECT with SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm adding support to our application to use SQL Server (it already works fine with MySQL) and hitting a problem with Hibernate/JDBC queries hanging after a few successes.  In this case the database is completely empty to start with.  The problem occurs while we are loading data into the database.

Again this works fine with MySQL.

Here's the hibernate sql statements (hangs on last entry):

```
Hibernate: select permission0_.dbID as dbID1_73_, permission0_.Created as Created2_73_, permission0_.dbVersion as dbVersio3_73_, permission0_.Origin as Origin4_73_, permission0_.Updated as Updated5_73_, permission0_.Entity as Entity6_73_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.Entity=?
Hibernate: select permission0_.dbID as dbID1_73_, permission0_.Created as Created2_73_, permission0_.dbVersion as dbVersio3_73_, permission0_.Origin as Origin4_73_, permission0_.Updated as Updated5_73_, permission0_.Entity as Entity6_73_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.Entity=?
Hibernate: select next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Permission (Created, dbVersion, Origin, Updated, Entity, dbID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Permission_Operations (Permission_id, T_element) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select permission0_.dbID as dbID1_73_, permission0_.Created as Created2_73_, permission0_.dbVersion as dbVersio3_73_, permission0_.Origin as Origin4_73_, permission0_.Updated as Updated5_73_, permission0_.Entity as Entity6_73_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.Entity=?
Hibernate: select permission0_.dbID as dbID1_73_, permission0_.Created as Created2_73_, permission0_.dbVersion as dbVersio3_73_, permission0_.Origin as Origin4_73_, permission0_.Updated as Updated5_73_, permission0_.Entity as Entity6_73_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.Entity=?
```

When I use SQL Server Studio I see the last query as State=SUSPENDED and Wait=LCK_M_S (see image below).

[image]

The last query will never finish/return.  I have left it running as much as 12 hours.  I did add a time-out of 60 seconds using javax.persistence.query.timeout hint with the Query just so it didn't hang forever.

Configuration:

- SQL Server 2017
- Hibernate 4.3.11.Final
- SQL Server Connector for JDBC 6.2.1.jre8
- Oracle Java 8

My persistence.xml:

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="25" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="true" />
        <!-- Tried with and without this: 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        -->
```

I also programetically set these values:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class  : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.connection.password      : <MASKED>
hibernate.connection.url           : jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver:1433;databaseName=xxx_test0
hibernate.connection.username      : xxx
hibernate.dialect                  : org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql                 : true
```

Comment: So session 57 is waiting on session 58 to release a lock. Why does session 58 have a lock? If you're loading data into empty database, why is more than one session/connection/thread involved? Who did what in session 58, and why hasn't that transaction been committed, to release the lock?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I was not doing a commit after the inserts but before the next select.  For some reason MySQL was fine with this, but SQL Server wanted to wait.

Adding a commit after all the inserts completed solved the problem.